# QGIS not interacting with iface from python class

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, multithreading

So I'm working on something where i need to use threads from python console of QGIS.
The following line of code adds layer successfully

```
iface.addVectorLayer("D:\ArcGIS Misc\Atlas\points.shp", 'Points', 'ogr')
```

But when i try to run the following code:

```
from threading import Thread
class AddLayer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.iface = iface

    def run(self):
        self.iface.addVectorLayer("D:\ArcGIS Misc\Atlas\points.shp", 'Points', 'ogr')
        print 'added'

AddLayer(iface).start()
```

then i only get **added** printed on the console but the layer is never added. When i do it from a class which is not inherited from Thread then it works fine. Help Needed

Answer (score 0):

You must register your layer with Map Layer Registry and then insert it into the Layer Tree (when working from the console, this is done automatically).
Try something like:

```
def run(self):
    self.iface.mapCanvas().freeze() # toggles rendering off to prevent deadlocking the map
    self.mylayer=self.iface.addVectorLayer("D:\ArcGIS Misc\Atlas\points.shp", 'Points', 'ogr')
    self.ProjInstance=QgsProject.instance() # get project instance
    self.root=self.ProjInstance.layerTreeRoot() # get layer tree
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.mylayer) # add layer to the registry
    self.root.addLayer(self.mylayer) # add layer to the layer tree
    self.iface.mapCanvas().freeze(False) # unfreeze renderer
    print 'added'
```

QgsProject and QgsMapLayerRegistry are in the qgis.core module:

```
from qgis.core import *
```