# Can't show new features on map with Python addfeature()

Tags: pyqgis, memory-layer, add-feature

I wrote a script to receiave NMEA from socket:
it gets NMEA sentences and creates points in a memory layer on the map.

It works, but map doesn't show new created points until I move or zoom it.

Here's the code:

```
from threading import Thread
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
import socket
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas

# get parts of nmea sentence
def nmea_split(nmea_string):
    return nmea_string.split(",")

# get lon/lat
def get_coord_gga(nmea_string):
    fields = nmea_split(nmea_string)
    # extract lon/lat from fields[2] and fields[4]
    lat = fields[2]
    lon = fields[4]
    return float(lat), float(lon)

# create socket UDP
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12345))

# set an empty layer
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "track", "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("point",  QVariant.Int),
                  QgsField("lon", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("lat", QVariant.Double)])
layer.updateFields() 
layer.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

def startLogger():
    point_num = 0
    while True:
        data = s.recvfrom(1024)
        nmea = data[0].decode()
        code = nmea_split(nmea)[0]
        # if data match GGA NMEA-sentence
        if code == "$GPGGA":
            point_num = point_num + 1
            lat, lon = get_coord_gga(nmea)
            f = QgsFeature()
            f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(lon, lat)))
            f.setAttributes([point_num, lon, lat])
            pr.addFeature(f) 
            layer.updateFields() 
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
            selection = layer.selectedFeatures()

Thread(target=startLogger).start()
```

points are correclty added, but I have to move map to show them.

I tried with qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas() zoom features, but it makes a sort of freezing to the map.

**UPDATE:**
to show what happens if I use some iface function, I add a gif:
[image]

As you see, when I simply add to code:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.zoomOut()
```

the zoom "freezes" map and deny to update map view to add new points.
I tried this, and other canvas updates but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the canvas with either `QgsMapCanvas.refresh()` or `QgsMapCanvas.refreshAllLayers()`?

Comment: If I try something like self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh() map freeze.. I can't nothing, map become white and I must restart Qgis. (think something as too slow to apply every loop).

Comment: You don't need to do `self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` every loop, just once at the end of the processing

Comment: tank you Matt, I understand what you say, but I need a continuos streaming,

Comment: I tried also to wait 5 secs after every lool (time-sleep(5) after iface.mapCanvas().refresh()) but it seems to have no changes (layers freeze)

Comment: See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448531/128665) for how to update the canvas after a fixed interval.

Comment: tank you Matt, I think this is not valid to me, because I get positions in realtime and I don't need a timelapse animating points. I need to update map view as a zoom or a move does. If I zoom or move map, new points appear, but I'm not able to do this by python (see post update why)

Comment: I understand you have a different use case and you don't want to animate a point, but the code using a QTimer can most likely be adapted for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Tank you to @Matt I found a solution.
Reading what he suggested in comment:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448531/128665

in section Qtimer I found the funtion witch can update map everytime a new point is added.
The function to add is:

```
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Tank you so much @Matt.

I also resolved correct use of iface.mapCanvas(), reading [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217512/137945).
To prevent freezing during canvas operations, you need to use:

```
iface.mapCanvas().freeze() # toggles rendering off to prevent deadlocking the map
canvas.zoomIn() # or whatever..
iface.mapCanvas().freeze(False) # unfreeze renderer
```

reading post is suggested to do this operations also before adding a layer to map.

p.s: it's quite ironic.. freeze canvas to not freeze map.